# How to get a list of major number -> driver associations

Tags: linux, drivers, devices

[*The Linux Programming Interface*](https://nostarch.com/tlpi) states:

> Each device driver registers its association with a specific major device ID, and this association provides the connection between the device special file and the device driver.

Is it possible to obtain the list of those associations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html) in the kernel source code documents the allocation process and lists all the allocated device numbers. `sd` gets a whole bunch of major device numbers because of the large number of devices it can handle: major 8 covers `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdp`, major 65 covers `/dev/sdq` to `/dev/sdaf`, 66 `/dev/sdag` to `/dev/sdav` and so on all the way to 135 for `/dev/sdig` to `/dev/sdiv` (for a total of 256 disk devices).

Answer (score 2):

The link in Stephen Kitt's answer provides the table for common device types. However some systems (for example device-mapper) don't hardcode their major numbers and instead obtain them dynamically.

In those cases, you can read the `/proc/devices` file to get a table of registered major numbers, along with a driver-specified description string that should point you in the right direction.

Note that, since the value is dynamically registered, it may change from boot to boot, depending on the order that the driver modules happen to register.

Comment: The link also describes (briefly) the dynamic allocation process  but it doesn’t mention `/proc/devices`, that is a very useful piece of information in the context of this question. Thanks!